# opencv transform tilt view to plan view

Tags: opencv, transform

Here is the picture I take with my USB camera. My camera has an angle with horizontal line, the target is on the bottom, with parallel and orthogonal lines delimiting rectangles. Post-it is a control marker of the center-rectangle.

[image: original view]
[image: point of view]

Then I process several step-by-step processing in order to adjust the 'tilt' of the view and to extract lines.
Here is the line extraction without transform :

{"type":"toGray"} => mat.cvtColor( cv4.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

{"type":"toBlur","size":10} => mat.gaussianBlur( new cv4.Size( size, size),0);

{"type":"toCanny","low":50,"high":150} => mat.canny( low_threshold, high_threshold);

{"type":"getLines","rho":1,"theta":0.017453292222222222,"threshold":15,"min_line_length":50,"max_line_gap":20 }] => let lines = mat.houghLinesP( rho, theta, threshold, min_line_length, max_line_gap);

Result is :
[image: result 1]

Now, I want to correct the tilt of view, using 'warpAffine' function, before extracting lines.
I select four points of the centered rectangle, in order to build two "three points array" (src, dst):
[image: transformation scheme]

```
matTransf = cv4.getAffineTransform( srcPoints, dstPoints);
resultMat = mat.warpAffine( matTransf, new cv4.Size( mat.cols, mat.rows));
```

The result is the following:
[image: final result]

Where is the mistake ?

I have tried too :

```
// four points at each corner of the rectangle, srcPoints for the  picture, and dstPoints for the theoric shape

// With getPerspectiveTransform
matTransf = cv4.getPerspectiveTransform( srcPoints, dstPoints);
resultMat = mat.warpPerspective( matTransf, new cv4.Size( mat.cols, mat.rows));

// With findHomography
let result = cv4.findHomography( srcPoints, dstPoints);
matTransf = result.homography;
resultMat = mat.warpPerspective( matTransf, new cv4.Size( mat.cols, mat.rows));
```

Result is :
[image: findHomograhy and getPerspectiveTransform]

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation is not an affinity, it is a perspective described by a homography. Select in the image four corners of a physical rectangle, map them to points in a rectangle with the same aspect ratio as the physical one, estimate the homography from them (findHomography), finally warp (warpPerspective).

Comment: findHomography and getPerspectiveTransform give almost the same result.

Comment: But perhaps 'map them to points in a rectangle with the same aspect ratio as the physical one' is a direction that I should investigate.

Comment: Explaination comes from "result image" display. My web page was displaying a squared picture instead the correct ratio width/height. The getPerspectiveTransform and warpPerspective functions are the good one (with 4 points). So suggest of Francesco is good too.